# Dither in Leech lattice quantization!

Tags: pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, discretization-and-quantization

Can you please help me how to generate a dither signal $\mathbf{U}$, where $\mathbf{U}$ is a random vector of length 24 that is uniformly distributed over the ***Voronoi region*** of the Leech lattice.

Best,

Farzad

Comment: If you can form the lattice modulo to the Voronoi region and you have a lattice basis, then here is an easy way: Generate a vector uniform over the lattice's base-parallelogram (Draw uniform over the unit box, then skew), and after that take the modulo of the result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all,

I refer readers to the paper, "Dithering in lattice quantization"by A. Kirac, in this paper he explains how to generate dither signals to have quantization error that is uniformly distributed on the voronoi cell.

Best,

Farzad